# Great example questions in the 'C' tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-wiki

I've been working on the [tag wiki for the 'C' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c&sort=info&pagesize=50) and was thinking it would be a good idea to link to some well formed questions as 'good' examples, in particular:

- A great over-all question. Something that contains all of the information that is needed to answer the question, but not overly-verbose
- An 'acceptable' homework question, where the student clearly identified their question as homework, briefly summarized what they had to do, showed us what they had so far and then explained where they were stuck.

Maybe others active in this tag have some items in their favorites that would fit the bill?

I suppose the questions that get linked might garner more up-votes, but I doubt that it would be significant. Or, perhaps would writing meta examples right into the wiki be better?

**Edit**

I just moved the list of common questions to the top of the tag wiki. We can almost tell when a new semester starts somewhere in the world when all of a sudden we see new incarnations of those questions. I don't know if people will see them before asking, but they do serve as a handy list of possible dupes (for when you know you saw almost the exact same question last semester, but can't seem to find it). The FAQ list (highly linked questions) helps, but not all of the common ones show up there.

Help in keeping that list up to date is greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 I didn't knew we could do that!

Comment: Ah; I was wondering who had written all that good text. Awesome.  I added a few frequently asked/frequently referred to questions with good answers.  I'm sure there are more; I don't know how big the list should get before it's too unwieldy.  Maybe we should put a photo of Dennis Ritchie on the page ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would probably be a good idea to link to some of the most commonly duplicated questions in the tag as well.  (Has this already been suggested anywhere?)  I'm thinking along the lines of [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Maybe something like "If you are about to ask for reading suggestions, please see the following questions first:" .. and perhaps, "If you question has anything at all to do with pointer arithmetic, please see these questions first ... " ?

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, I think that would be helpful to people who are searching *and* cut down on some of the duplication at the same time.

Comment: agreed. Most of our 'just-worded-differently-enough-to-not-be-a-duplicate' questions are usually the same basic pointer questions warmed over at least 1x a week.

Comment: List added :) ...